# com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField not found in ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I am trying to use ORM lite in my android application. In the example code there is an import

```
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
```

However when eclipse does not see this import nor does my project buil

```
The import com.j256.ormlite.field cannot be resolved
```

I am using ormlite-android-4.41.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote the ORMLite documentation:  [1.1 Downloading ORMLite Jar](http://ormlite.com/docs/downloading)

> For use with Android applications, you should download the
>   ormlite-android-4.41.jar and ormlite-core-4.41.jar files